# Create a function which takes in a word and spells it out, by consecutively adding letters until the full word is completed

Tags: javascript

Create a function which takes in a word and spells it out, by consecutively adding letters until the full word is completed.

This is my code for the solution. I am super new to JS. Could someone tell me the problem? Thank you.

```
function spelling(str) {
    var str1 = [...str]
    var n 
    str1.index[n] = str.slice(0, n+1)   
    return str1
}
```

**Expected output:**

```
Test.assertSimilar(spelling("bee"), ['b', 'be', 'bee'])
Test.assertSimilar(spelling("cake"), ['c', 'ca', 'cak', 'cake'
```

**Actual output:**

> TypeError: Cannot set property 'undefined' of undefined at spelling at
>   Object.handleError at ContextifyScript.Script.runInThisContext at
>   Object.exports.runInThisContext

Comment: What is `str.index[n]` supposed to be? `str1` doesn't have an `index` property, and you never set `n` to anything.

Comment: how does `n` get updated?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you never initialized `n`.

In addition, what is `str1.index`? It does not exist. If you want to access a cell in an array you should use: `array[i]`.

Moreover, after you defined n, you need to update it for every char.

What I did was to fix all of what I mentioned above, and I created an empty array, and for each char of `str` I'm pushing to the array a slice of `str` and update `n` (`++n` means to use `n` after increment it by 1).

```js
function spelling(str) {
  var str1 = [];
  let n = 0;
  for (c in str)
    str1.push(str.slice(0, ++n));
  return str1;
}

console.log(spelling('bee'));
```

Comment: Thank you it works! Can i know what is 'c' in for (c in str) ?

Comment: @Chasuna `c` means for every `c` in `str`, it's for every index (between 0 and `str.length`-1) of str. It's like a for loop but without defining the entire ` for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) `.

Answer (score 1):

```
function spelling(str) {
    return str.split('').map((el,i)=>str.slice(0,i+1));
}
```

Map can take a second parameter which is the index of the array that map is being called on.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `substring` to achieve this.

> The substring() method extracts the characters from a string, between
>   two specified indices, and returns the new sub string.

```js
function spelling(str) {
  let result = [];
  for (let i = 1; i <= str.length; i++) {
    result.push(str.substring(0, i));
  }
  return result;
}

console.log(spelling('bee'));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * spelling("hello") // Returns ["h", "he", "hel", "hell", "hello"]
 */
function spelling(str) {
  var arr = [];
  var len = str.length;
  while (len) {
    arr.unshift(str.substring(0, len--));
  }
  return arr;
}
```